# Game Boy Camera – How to identify this connector?

Tags: connector, identification, surface-mount

I want to get another male socket for the JST-looking connector that the 1998 [Game Boy Camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Camera) uses.  I haven't been able to identify it though – the pitch looks to be exactly 1.5mm center-to-center.  Can I still buy this connector?

[image: Image compilation]

Comment: Not sure where you're getting 4/3. That looks bang-on 1.5mm. Uncommon, but definitely out there. Look at DigiKey under rectangular connectors. Looks like very common stuff that JST et al make. 1.27mm would be the "standard" half-size pitch, but it looks wider than that.

Comment: Oops, I did the math wrong.  9 pins, but it's 8 spaces.  I'll edit the question.  Looks like it might be a JST ZH connector.  I'll do more research tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the datasheet, I'm increasingly certain that it's a [JST ZH 9-pin connector](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eZH.pdf).  I can't find any measurement that doesn't seem to match.

EDIT: I ordered a JST ZH-9, and it was a perfect fit.  Thanks for the help.